# ABPersonSetImageData is extremely slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, abaddressbook

I am writing an app that interfaces with the iPhone address book.

Here is the relevant section of my code (from `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`)

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
       didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image 
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    ABPersonSetImageData(record, (__bridge CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(image), &error);
}
```

My app lets you take a picture with the camera (using `UIImagePictureController`), and then stores it as the contact for someone in your address book.

I'm finding that the operation above hangs for 5-10 seconds.  1) Is there a better approach?  2) Why is this so slow?

Comment: Have you tried using a JPEG representation?

Comment: Yes, its probably 25% faster, but still takes more than 5 seconds. I've got to think there's a faster way to do this though...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Saving as a JPEG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation):

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation (UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);
```

will be faster than [`UIImagePNGRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation), especially if `compressionQuality` is set to a low value. However, this is still a CPU intensive process, so there's no way to avoid the wait.

The best you can do is show a message that work is being done, so the interface doesn't feel unresponsive. Use something like [`SVProgressHUD`](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) to do that.

Comment: Thanks!  It makes me wonder how it gets done so fast in the native Contacts app.  I'm guessing a background thread?